# how to restart the program automatically in the terminal, python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot! When I run it through the terminal, it works well. But if the Internet is lost, the program stops with the error code:

> ```
> raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)".
> ```

I need the program to automatically start when the Internet appears.
But the solution should not be such that this program runs every time the computer is turned on.
I wish there was a program "A" that would run my program with a bot.
If I don't run program "A", then my program won't start automatically

Вот мой код для примера:

(Here is my code:)

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('*************')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(my_mes):
    try:
        if my_mes.text == "/help":
            bot.send_message(my_mes.from_user.id, "hi")
        elif 0 < int(my_mes.text) < 5:
            num = int(my_mes.text) + 1
            bot.send_message(my_mes.from_user.id, str(num))
    except:
        bot.send_message(my_mes.from_user.id, "write /help.")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=999999)
        while True:
            time.sleep(100)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        time.sleep(6)
```

instead of this:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

In my case, this solved the problem. By the way, many people recommend using a webhooks instead of pooling.